# Error when creating search bar for Tkinter table GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a search bar where you can type in a keyword and it will output the row with the keyword from my tkinter table, but I am receiving this error when I input a keyword.   ‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

```
TypeError: DisplaySearchResult() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DisplaySearchResult() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

1. Here is my code and [csv](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tkinter/comments/ze1gy8/how_to_create_a_search_bar_to_search_keywords_in/)
2. Here is what the UI currently looks like
   [image]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import csv

root = Tk()
root.title("Python - Import CSV File To Tkinter Table")
width = 900
height = 600
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)


TableMargin = Frame(root, width=500)
TableMargin.pack(side=TOP)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=VERTICAL)
tree = ttk.Treeview(TableMargin, columns=("Link", "Name", "Email"), height=400, selectmode="extended", yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.heading('Link', text="Link", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Name', text="Name", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Email', text="Email", anchor=W)
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=300)
tree.pack()

with open('output.csv') as f:
    # reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 0:
            continue
        link: str = row[0]
        name: str = row[1]
        email: str = row[2]
        # specialty: str = row[3]
        tree.insert("", 0, values=(link, name, email))
        
root = Tk()
Searchbar = Entry(root)
Searchbar.pack()
SearchString = StringVar(Searchbar, "")
Searchbar.config(textvariable = SearchString)

SearchResultBar = Label(root)
SearchResultBar.pack()

def DisplaySearchResult():
  Keyword = SearchString.get()
  # write some code to search your csv data and get a string to describe the search result, which we'll call SearchResult
  SearchString.set(SearchResult)

Searchbar.bind('<Return>', DisplaySearchResult, add = '+')
Searchbar.bind('<FocusOut>', DisplaySearchResult, add = '+')

def generatecode(self):
    pass  # Do stuff here


#============================INITIALIZATION==============================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Also, are you aware that functions bound to events will be called with an `event` parameter?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, edited. How should I format the function with an event parameter?

Comment: Define `DisplaySearchResult` to accept this parameter: `def DisplaySearchResult(event)`. This is a very fundamental aspect of tkinter programming, which should be covered in just about any tkinter tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you need to allow for Event in your function args.

use `def DisplaySearchResult(event)` or `def DisplaySearchResult(*args)` (more usefull for .trace() methods which has 3-4 args passed)

A few other points:

- Don't use `Tk()` twice, create a new window with `TopLevel()`
- If you only use Treeview from ttk then only import that `from tkinter.ttk import Treeview`
- when using bind() event is passed and you can get the widget with `event.widget` to get the bound wiget.
- Tkinter is best used inside a class.

To center your window in screen with some pixel boarder size:

```py
    h_offset = 300 ##border top+bottom
    v_offset = 300 ##border left+right
    ws = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
    hfw = (ws-h_offset)/2
    hfh = (hs-v_offset)/2
    root.geometry(f'{ws-h_offset}x{hs-v_offset}+{int(ws/2-hfw)}+{int(hs/2-hfh))}')
```